# Single Regular expression for replace tr and td with newline and tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have table structure in HTML. I need to replace `<tr>` with `/n` and `<td>` with '/t' using regex. What I have done is as follows:

```
var dataval = [].slice.call($("#printdiv").find("table tr")).map(function(row){
    var a = row.textContent.trim().replace(/td/gi,"\t");
    return a;
}).join("\r\n");
```

It is working partially but `tab` is not coming between `<td>`.

Comment: [Never use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan ok. Can you suggest a better solution?>

Comment: Can you be sure that the `<TR>` and `<TD>` are on the same line?

Comment: @Santhucool I added an answer for you.

Comment: The `replace` in your code has issue. You could try: `replace("<td>", "\t")`, or `replace("td", "\t")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firstly, never use RegEx to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Secondly you can achieve this by building an 2d array represent all the `tr` and `td` elements in your table, like this:

```
var tableData = $('table tr').map(function() {
    return [$(this).find('td').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get()];
}).get();
```

Note that the returned value of the second `map()` call needs to be placed in another array as jQuery annoyingly flattens out the first child array in the response of `map()`.

From there you can build a string with each cell delimited with a tab, and each row with a new line. Something like this:

```
var output = '';
$.each(tableData, function(i, row) {
    $.each(row, function(i, cell) {
        output += cell + '\t';
    })
    output += '\n';
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/adpnyLun/)